# small signal equivalent circuit with BJT and MOSFET problem

Tags: mosfet, bjt

Here's my problem.
[image]

i've been trying to draw the small signal equivalent circuit. And this is what i have

[image]
but i feel something's wrong because when i calculate voltage gain i dont have to use gm of the BJT. can you guys show me where did i do wrong?

Comment: The gain is 2 by simple inspection and I never used the model or gm. I can't tell from your scrawlings what your conclusion was.

Comment: sorry for scrawling. i have edit the image. i want to ask if my small signal equivalent circuit is drawn right?

Comment: By inspection - M2 is a source follower (unity gain), without C2 whatever voltage drop there is across the emitter resistor ( 18k) you'll get twice that voltage across the collector resistor (2x18k). (*Hint* Ic is almost equal to Ie)

Answer (score 1):

Your small-signal equivalent circuit is wrong. In your sketched circuit you connected the mosfet's drain to the bjt's collector and the mosfet's gate to the bjt's emitter.

To draw a small-signal equivalent circuit you should substitute each device with its small-signal equivalent, *respecting* the position of the terminals.